Can I create a many to many relation using a junction table with a junction table
I want to create a m2m relation between two tables and one of the table is a junction table for m2m relation. So basically, I have 3 tables and 2 can be joined using a m2m. But in order to join three tables, I have two options, one is to create a m2m with the third table and the already created junction table and the other approach is to create a table which has foreign key of all the three tables. Which of the above approach is suitable.
The tables for Promo and Prize and Screen are:
CREATE TABLE Promo (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    promo_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    promo_subtype VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
    promo_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    win_probability FLOAT NULL,
    start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    end_date TIMESTAMP NULL,
    prize_cap_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
    );

CREATE TABLE Prize (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    prize_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    prize_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    prize_image VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT prize_company_fk FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Screen (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ownership_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'own' CHECK (ownership_type IN (/* list all valid ownership_type options */)),
    name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Screen',
    location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Static' CHECK (location IN (/* list all valid LocationChoices options */))
);

So basically the promo is actually a spin wheel that is displayed on the screen and the table stores information like the expiry date and the design of the wheel. And the Prize table saves prizes that are displayed on the wheel. The prizes are created without relation with promo as a prize created can be used with other promo. The linking is made between promo and prizes when a promo is created with the prizes associated with it.
The reason for these m2m fields are because I want to save the prize cap for 2 cases:

I want to save prize cap for a prize that will be common across all screen it is running on so if 1 screen uses 1 prize, this will have affect on all screens and the count will be decremented on all screens. This is implemented using the m2m between promo and prize.

The second case is that I want to save prize cap for a prize specific to a promo and specific to a screen. So if a promo is running on multiple screens, the cap of each prize is different across all screens and does not have any affect on each other. This is implemented using the m2m relation of Screen with the PromoPrize or a table with ids of Screen, Promo and Prize so that information of a prize specific to a Screen and Promo can be saved.


The two approaches to implement table with relation to three tables are:
CREATE TABLE PromoPrizeScreen (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    prize_cap INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    prize_used INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    promo_prize_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    screen_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (promo_prize_id) REFERENCES PromoPrize (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (screen_id) REFERENCES Screen (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE PromoPrizeScreen2 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    prize_cap INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    prize_used INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    promo_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    prize_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    screen_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (promo_id) REFERENCES Promo (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (prize_id) REFERENCES Prize (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (screen_id) REFERENCES Screen (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

I am implementing this in Django so these are the django models:
class PromoPrizeScreen(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prize_cap = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    prize_used = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    promo_prize = models.ForeignKey(PromoPrize, related_name='promo_prize_screens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    screen = models.ForeignKey(Screen, related_name='promo_prize_screens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PromoPrizeScreen2(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prize_cap = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    prize_used = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    promo = models.ForeignKey(Promo, related_name='promo_prize_screens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prize = models.ForeignKey(Prize, related_name='promo_prize_screens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    screen = models.ForeignKey(Screen, related_name='promo_prize_screens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


The main question is not how to do this technically, but how the "concept" looks like. Exactly what do you want to link together? What data do you want to store in the relation itself?

What is the Prize model doing for example, what does it store (represents)?

So not clear to me how Promo and Prize relate to each other, and to Screen, or why this needs two tables at all. Please explain exactly what you are trying to represent.

For case 1, it sounds like you need a Promo_Prize table which is many-many between only Promo and Prize (note this should not have an Id column, just a composite of the two other IDs). Then for case 2, you need a Screen_PromoPrize table, a many-many between only Screen and Promo_Prize, so although three IDs are present, the actual FKs are (ScreenId) and (PrizeId, PromoId)
